# Updated full calendar events are not rendering after adding new events in events array using api

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am using full-calendar version 5. What I have implemented in version 4 is whenever month is changed I call API to fetch events for that month and then reassign the events array used. That used to work just fine but now in version 5 it's not working.
I have tried the approach suggested in their doc to reassign the array and also tried the "deepChangeDetection" option but none of this helped.

```
<full-calendar #calendar deepChangeDetection="true" [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>


calendarEvents:any[] = [
      { title: 'event 1', date: '2020-07-01' },
      { title: 'event 2', date: '2020-07-02' }
    ];
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    events: this.calendarEvents
  };

//this is a example method in my code I have used calendar instance and used it's next and pre month method and bind them on custom buttons
  nextMonth(arg) {
    this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvets.concat([{ title: 'event 3', date: '2020-07-03' }]);
  }
```

Here is sample code

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-leaf-mtqxh

Comment: I never posted questions on StackOverflow before so please ignore any mistake made by me also suggest any changes in question that can make it more easy to understand.

Comment: your link is dead. You might try to reassign `calendarOptions`. `full-calendar` is not directly bound to `calendarEvents`

Comment: Thank you @canbax I was trying to update the source event array object and was thinking that full calendar will update its events but as they included events property in new options settings that were not working. In order to update now, we have to update the events variable of calendarOptions so in my example what I have to do is this.calendarOptions.events = ["new events"]